# CSV Import with double double quotes in first data row SSIS error

Tags: csv, ssis

I have column names in row one of a CSV file with double quotes as the text delimiter. There is a column in each data row that could have double quotes but these have previously been tested and changed to have an escape quote.

The process works correctly for every line except the first data row. If there are double-double quotes in the first row of data the process fails to parse correctly and fails.

I have several locations later in the file that have the double-double quotes which parse correctly.

NOTE: Moving this same row later in the file the file will still fail on that row with the double-double quotes.

**UPDATE:** using data flow task every line which has a comma after the double-double quotes fails. I do not understand this issue as I can open in excel and the columns parse correctly. Is there a way to use a script task to open the file in excel and save as excel file format?

Comment: You data looks like header -> `""col1"",""Col2""` data -> `"squid", ""chewy""` It will parse the data row fine but blows chunks at header?

Comment: @billinkc The header does not have Quotes. So it looks like `col1, col2,...,col14` with a `{LF}` row delimiter. The first data row has double-double quotes in the 12th column, like -> `" data data data ""in quotes"" more data"`

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a problem with the EOL character being different to the rest of the lines? Can you check what is the exact message you get on the error?

Comment: @bartover The EOL character is the same as every other line. The exact error is a truncation error for the following (13th) column. Since the text in the 12th has commas in it and the import is not reading the double quotes it is parsing out all text after the comma into the 13th column which is a date type column.

Comment: If I remove the double-double quotes in that row of data and save the file it parses correctly.

Comment: What's the SQL Server/SSIS version?

Comment: @bartover 2008. The issue is in the actual connection manager. A preview shows the exact line of the issue every time. I have updated my original claim by mentioning that after testing I find that any line with double-double quotes that has commas after will fail to parse correctly.

It's as though it sees the first quotation mark and does not look for any escape quotes.